# How to make an annonimizer with random proxy/UA from files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

im trying to make an anonymizer with python and im not really sure which "loop" to use (as you can tell im still pretty new to all this)

so far i have this:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib


br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

proxylist=open("/home/xyz/proxylist.txt","r+")
ualist=open=("/home/xyz/ualist.txt","r+")



def changeuseragent(useragent):
    br.addheaders=[('User-agent',useragent)]

def addproxy(proxy):
    br.set_proxies({"http":proxy})

def changecookie():
     cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
     br.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)

changeuseragent(useragent)
addproxy(proxy)
changecookie()
z=br.open("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com")
print z.read()
```

before i had the above two "open file" lines i had two lines with a proxy and UserAgent values, so i removed those and opened two files i made with several options of each type(each line is 1 option)

what i want is to write a loop so that every time i run it, it will access the website with a random proxy and useragent, from the list.
the main issue i have is im not sure how to build it and if i should use `while True` or `if` or maybe even `try`.

ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get lines of a file use:

```
lines = open(path,"r").readlines()
```

To select a random element from, let's say, an array of lines:

```
import random #preferably at the top of the script
myline = random.choice(lines)
```

To strip the line of harmful newlines and spaces:

```
cleanline = line.strip()
```

To repeat your task:

```
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

def open_page(url,agent,proxy):
    changeuseragent(agent.strip()) # pass br here, or move above lines out
    addproxy(proxy.strip()) # into the global scope
    changecookie()

    return br.open(url)

# if script is executed, not imported. This line below is common magic.
if __name__=="__main__": 
    # TODO: open your files
    somelines = file(path,"r").readlines()
    #
    running = True
    while running:
        # TODO: select a line
        oneline = random.choice(lines)
        secondline = random.choice(otherlines)
        #
        f = open_page(your_url,agentline,proxyline)
        print f.read() #<or do whatever you wish
        f.close() #<not necessary

        running = raw_input("x and enter to exit: ").lower().startswith("x")
    # And on it goes.
```

Edit: I've added some pseudocode. You need to modify more-or-less-obvious lines.

On topic: Loop like above is very common in interactive console scripts.

Comment: WOW - that seems WAY WAY WAY over the scope of my understanding at the moment >.< thank you for trying tho!

Comment: just saw your edit - and had a good night sleep.... thank you very much im pretty sure i get it now!